# R: Is there a faster way to convert a column from character to POSIXct datatime in a big data frame?

Tags: database, r, sqlite, data.table, plyr

The raw data are high frequency stock price data by 3 seconds of thousands of stocks in several months stored in text files. I use `RSQLite` to write the data to local SQLite database. As far as I tried, `Date` or `POSIXct` objects cannot be stored in its original format but integers. I need to store them as `TEXT` in SQLite. The database file turns out to be nearly 1.5GB. When I need to use the data and perform some time series operations (e.g. aggregate data to 10-minite frequency for each stock), I need to convert the `character` column to `POSIXct` type, which costs a long time due to the large size of the data frame loaded in R environment.

Are there better practices to handle all this? Like using `data.table` and `plyr` packages?

My primary concern is performance issues and flexibility to interoperate with time series packages like `xts`.

Answer (score 2):

SQLite does indeed lack a proper datetime type; you may want to consider another backend such as PostgreSQL which does (and RPostgreSQL gets dates and times back and forth to R correctly).

For parsing / converting of date times *text* to POSIXct, your best bet is Simon's [fasttime](http://rforge.net/fasttime/) provided your data is in proper ISO format such as 2014-03-06 22:23:24.123456.

Comment: fasttime also assumes GMT.